# My calculator android application crashed after i added the function given below

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my xml code

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSign"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"    
    android:text="±"
    android:onClick="ProcessSignInput" />
```

Here is my java code

```
public void ProcessSignInput(View v)
{
    Button btn = (Button) v;
    if(inputText.length() > 0 && currentInput!="0")
    {
        if(currentInput.charAt(0) == '-')
        {
            inputText.setText(currentInput.subSequence(1, inputText.length()));
        }
        else
        {
            inputText.setText("-" + currentInput.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the line for current input

```
String currentInput = inputText.getText().toString();
```

Every thing was working perfecctly before i added these lines.Nw app just crashes can anyone explain what is causing this crash thanx in advance.

Comment: If you have a crash, please post the stacktrace. Also don't compare String using `==`, use `equals()`.

Comment: Are you retrieving this on onCreate() method String currentInput = inputText.getText().toString();?

Comment: No i wrote this code outside my on create method
just at the beginning of extends activity method.
yes this line was causing error but why?

Comment: @Programmingcat Have you checked that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't write that code  outside your on create method just at the beginning of extends activity method

You have to call this on Click event of your Button. Use this. If you are calling this it outside of your onCreate() method

```
String currentInput = inputText.getText().toString();
```

It will be always null because at that time you din't find ID for your EditText or TextView UI element and that value or string contains null data. So it will be always null pointer exception.

```
public void ProcessSignInput(View v)
{
Button btn = (Button) v;
String currentInput = inputText.getText().toString();
if(inputText.length() > 0 && !currentInput.equalsIgnoreCase(0))
{
    if(currentInput.charAt(0) == '-'))
    {
        inputText.setText(currentInput.subSequence(1, inputText.length()));
    }
    else
    {
        inputText.setText("-" + currentInput.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Also don't compare String using ==, use

```
equals() or equalsIgnoreCase()
```

Comment: The String.charAt() method returns a char type, which does not have an equals() or an equalsIgnoreCase() method.

Comment: @Programmingcat Wel come. Glad to help